# Make my ejabberd server able to communicate with others XMPP servers. (SRV Records)

Tags: dns, ejabberd, google-compute-engine

I installed ejabberd on a compute engine instance, and it's working well.

I'd like to communicate with other XMPP server, in particular with the XMPP service on App Engine. I've read that i've to change my SRV records and the SRV records of my domain host.

Here my question: since my server XMPP is on compute engine, who i have to contact in order to have the SRV records edited?
The ports in my server are open, port 5222 for c2s connections, and 5269 for s2s connections.

The command
dig _xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com srv
works, then i can reach the gmail contacts, now i need to be reached by them.
I tought about using dyndns, but reading this:
http://www.dyncommunity.com/questions/1136/adding-srv-records-for-google-talk-federation-to-c.html
i've found that i need a paid account, so that's not what i want.
Thanks in advance.

In addition, i'll add some posts i've read about it:
http://www.ejabberd.im/node/2976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, that was due to my ignorance about these themes.
As the name says, DNS mean Domain Name System, i needed a domain.
So i purchased a domain, then i went on my account of goDaddy.com and set the DNS of the domain registered with another registar, making it point to my instance of Compute Engine.
Now my server XMPP is reachable by others XMPP servers, included gmail.

I found very helpful these links:
http://blog.kenweiner.com/2008/05/ejabberd-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-ami.html
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4041/managing-domain-names-with-offsite-dns

I hope this is helpful for someone :-)